# Selecting from SVG with node as argument throws DOM Exception 12

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I'm at a loss as to what's causing the DOM Exception 12. What little I can find is that it has to do with invalid selectors?

For background:

We have a scatter graph which is an SVG object with lots of circles in it.

When you hover over a circle, we want to have access to the data it represents to show a tooltip.

At the moment we're listening to events via backbone (scatter graph falls into a larger application), so we have access to the element node that was the current target via `e.currentTarget`.

On the first pass, we simply did

```
d3.select(e.currentTarget) // from here we can access the datum() method
```

But since we now want to use the VML compatibility layer [r2d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/), the caveat is that if we want to select elements inside the SVG we have to select from the svg.

> Queries for SVG elements must origin from the SVG node. Example use svg.select('rect') NOT d3.select('rect')

We have access to the D3 wrapped SVG element via `this.svg` in the hover event. However when I call:

```
this.svg.select(e.currentTarget)
```

I get a DOM Exception 12.

```
Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
    d3_select d3.v2.js:3578
    (anonymous function) d3.v2.js:372
    d3_selectionPrototype.select d3.v2.js:3606
    Backbone.View.extend.mouseEnterBin graph.js:828
    jQuery.each.jQuery.event.special.(anonymous function).handle jquery-1.7.2.js:3616
    jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.js:3332
    jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

When I add a `debugger;` line before we try the select, I'm able to this.svg.selectAll('circle') and confirm that the node `e.currentTarget` does exist in that set.

Any advice or help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector argument in `selection.select(selector)` must be a string (e.g. 'circle') or a function. It seems that in your case it is a DOM node.

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select:

> For each element in the current selection, selects the first
>   descendant element that matches the specified selector string. ...
>
> The selector may also be specified as a function that returns an
>   element, or null if there is no matching element. ...

If you have access to a node, you can transform it to a d3 selection using `d3.select(node)` (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select).

From you description it seems that you simply want to create a D3 selection from the e.currentTarget; so `d3.select(e.currentTarget)` would suffice.

Comment: Ahh, thankyou this makes everything make sense then. What I was getting hung up on was the r2d3 requirement which said selectors for svg elements need to be selected from the svg element itself. Which isn't necessary if you already have a reference to the node because you can't select like that with a node in the first place.